# How would I modify this counting script to account for duplicate values with different versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, devops

Basically I have a stdin that looks like this

```
5 3
calculator-2.4
data_feed-3.2
protocol_adapter-1.0
protocol_adapter-1.1
local_network_connector-3.4
data_feed-3.2.1
calculator-2.4.1
protocol_adapter-1.2
```

where the 5 rows, starting from the top, are current versions of something and the 3 are the new versions I need to compare the current versions to and determind if I need to upgrade. The answer will be a single int that will indicate the number of upgrades required. So for the example given the answer would be 4, calculator-2.4 data_feed-3.2 protocol_adapter-1.0 protocol_adapter-1.1 would be the ones needing upgrades. But if I have something like

```
6 4
integrator-4.6.3
data_feed-1.1
calculator-3.6
protocol_adapter-2.2.1
data_feed-1.1
integrator-4.6.2
data_feed-1.1.1
protocol_adapter-2.3
data_feed-1.2
validator-1.0
```

Where the data feed upgrade is in there twice my code will not pick it up. The answer to this second one would be 5 too. I have attached my code below.

```
import sys
line1 = sys.stdin.readline()
const = int(line1[0])
new = line1[2]
count = 0
dict1 = {}
listy = []
ans = 0
trbl = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if count < const:
        line = line.rstrip()
        listy.append(line)
        count+=1
    else:
        line = line.rstrip()
        data = line.split('-')
        dict1[data[0]]=data[1]

for value in listy:
    values1 = value.split('-')
    if values1[0] in dict1.keys():
        if value[1] != dict1[values1[0]]:
            ans+=1
            trbl.append(value)
    else:
        pass
print(ans)
print(trbl)
```

My code answers the first one but if there's more than one instance of a new version on the same component it won't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks if the version is not equal to the version stored in dict1:

```
if value[1] != dict1[values1[0]]:
    ans+=1
    trbl.append(value)
```

This means that if the version is in the dict1, it would be ignored. You might want to try and create a second map that keeps track of the number of times the latest version is seen. Something like:

```
import sys
line1 = sys.stdin.readline()
const = int(line1[0])
new = line1[2]
count = 0
dict1 = {}
set1 = set([]) # this set keeps track of the occurence of the latest version
listy = []
ans = 0
trbl = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    if count < const:
        line = line.rstrip()
        listy.append(line)
        count+=1
    else:
        line = line.rstrip()
        data = line.split('-')
        dict1[data[0]]=data[1]

for value in listy:
    values1 = value.split('-')
    if values1[0] in dict1.keys():
        if value[1] != dict1[values1[0]]:
            ans+=1
            trbl.append(value)
    elif values1[0] in set1: # same version already occurred, so add it to ans and trbl
        ans+=1
        trbl.append(value)
    else:
        set1.add(values1[0]) # add to set after the first occurence
print(ans)
print(trbl)
```

Comment: Would set be a list or a dictionary? You have it as a dictionary but are appending it like a list?

Comment: It is a Set, which is like a dictionary, but only has the key